# Ubuntu non riconosce adattatore wifi 22.04

Tags: wireless, adapter

Salve, ho installato ubuntu tramite macchina virtuale Oracle vm virtualbox ma non riesco a collegarmi al wifi.

Comment: English only please

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the Guest is a *virtual* machine. The Guest cannot see any real hardware. It sees only the virtual devices provided by the Host.

WiFi and all other real hardware is handled by the VM Host (not the Guest).

Your Guest should connect to the VirtualBox-provided LAN connection, which is the network access provided by the Host.